# Create a function that can be used anywhere within Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, function, class

I want to create a number of functions in my plugin 'membershipintegration.php' which can be called anywhere on my Wordpress site.

I thought that if I created a class and defined a public function within the class in the membershipintegration.php I could use it wherever I liked.

```
class MembershipIntegration
{
  public function switchmembership () {
  echo 'some code'
  }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work and I've used 'function_exists' on my sandbox page and it says the function isn't active.

Any thoughts much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: My best effort so far has been to remove the class and make the function just a normal function (not public function) and use this code to include it in any PHP file I want to use the function in. This seems a bit clunky though, right? 

`$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "/wp-content/plugins/membershipsintegration/membershipintegration.php";
   include_once($path);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress automatically load your `membershipintegration.php` when the plugin is active, then any function created inside this file or any other included file is automatically loaded and available in any place.

The recommendation is:

Create a file called `functions.php`

```
<?php

function myFunctionOne(){
    //some code
}
```

and then in your `membershipintegration.php` use:

```
require __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'functions.php';
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion rafrsr. It doesn't seem to work though!

I've tried putting the class / public function in both the main plugin file and an included functions.php file and I still can't call the function in another php file.

Any other thoughts on what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: don't put the function inside a class,  or you need create a static method or instantiate the class before use the method. Create the function in the file and use as is.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a function inside a class. PHP classes consist of properties and methods. The keyword to define a user-defined method is `function` so it's a little confusing.

To access a public method, you first need an instance of that method. For instance:

```
$s = new MembershipIntegration();
```

Then you can access the public method:

```
$s->switchmembership();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
        require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'file-name.php';
        new CLassName();
?>
```

put this code on your plugin index file then it can be call any where if your plugin is activate